# API Gateway Proxy Without URL Redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

- I’m using AWS API Gateway at https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home
- I did all of the steps to set up a proxy for http://foo.com (example)
- I deployed it and the URL is http://bar.com (example)
- When I go to http://bar.com/hello, it redirects me to http://foo.com/hello
- I want it to stay at http://bar.com/hello, but deliver the contents from http://foo.com/hello like a normal proxy service

Note: My primary intent is to get around CORS issues with a service

Comment: What is the foo service using? Do you have control over it or not? Can you change it

Comment: What service are you proxying? That would be what is sending the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that whatever service you're using is forcing the redirect like @Steve's comment mentioned. They might be forcing HTTP_REFERER to be a certain domain.
Since I don't know what service you're calling this is just a guess.